# Issues mocking a constructable API class with methods that return promises in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have an API class:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class API {
  constructor(axiosConfig) {
    this.instance = axios.create({ ...axiosConfig });
  }

  async getSomeData(params) => {
    let result = await this.instance.get('some_data_endpoint', { params: params });
    return result.data;
  }
}
```

And a component that first constructs the API class, then calls the provided endpoint in a useEffect hook:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { API } from './API';
import { axiosConfig } from './constants'

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const apiInstance = new API(axiosConfig);
  const [someData, setSomeData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiInstance.getSomeData({ some_param: 'some_param_value' }).then(data => {
      setSomeData(data);
    })
  }, [])
}
```

And the following jest test:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent'
import API from './API';

jest.mock('./API', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getSomeData: () => {
        return []
      }
    }
  })
});

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<SomeComponent />);
  });

  it('does some work', () => {
    // do assertions 
  })
})
```

The issue I'm facing is that the API gets mocked, but the methods within the mock implementation aren't defined on the mock when I try to run the above test. This results in a `API.getSomeData is not a function` error.

Hopefully looking for anything I might be missing regarding how jest mocking would work for the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this and using the create-react-app framework,  my issue turned out to be in the default CRA config for jest. CRA resets all jest mocks before test runs by default. To disable this reset you can add some config under jest in your package.json for the project:

```
"jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
}
```